How to increase IPController buffer size in ipcluster?
I start a cluster on my machine
ipcluster start -n 14

and do some python calculations on it. After a while the cluster prints out to terminal:
[IPController] 550 records with total buffer size 1077615077 exceeds limit: 1073741824. Culled oldest 105 records.

and then the cluster crashes. I have a lot more RAM available than 1GB. Is there a way to increase the buffer size?
